# Why do I receive the 'expected expression' error when compiling this C code

Tags: c, cs50

How do I get this code to reject numbers (in the form of floats) which are negative? This is part of problem set one for cs50? When attempting to compile, an error is generated in "n = get_int(%n, prompt"

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//prompts user to submit amount of change
int get_positive_float(string prompt); 
int main(void)
{
    float change = get_positive_float("Change owed: ");
    printf("%.2f\n", change);
}

//ensures user submits a positive number
int get_positive_float(string prompt)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int(%n, prompt);
    }
    while (n < 0);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: %n should be in double quotes, also what do you mean by 'reject' ?

Comment: I want the program to reject--ask the user once more--should they provide an integer that is not positive

Comment: If I understand correctly, get_positive_float checks if the input is positve, and returns 1 if it is. If that's the case, you should use an if-statement instead of a while loop.

Comment: Your function is called `get_positive_float` but it returns an `int`. ???

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
    n = get_int(%n, prompt);
```

Is wrong. `%` is the modulo operator and needs two operands. Maybe you intended this to be some kind of format string? You don't have a definition of `get_int` present, so it's hard to say.

As an editorial aside, it's a bit weird to have a function called `get_positive_float` that returns an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I want this line to return the user to the prompt should they not provide a positive float. This line should direct them to the string prompt above, no?

Comment: No, that line is just invalid syntax. What does `get_int` expect? A format string? Then maybe you want `get_int("%s", string)`? Or just `get_int(string)`?

Answer (score 0):

Gonna warn you right now, the way CS50 handles C strings and I/O is *extremely* misleading, and it *will* lead to heartburn later on.  I understand the motivation (put a friendly, high-level interface on unfriendly, low-level operations), but they botched it badly.

From the [CS50 Programmer's Manual entry for `get_int`](https://man.cs50.io/3/get_int), the first argument needs to be type `char *` (`string` is a typedef name, or alias, for `char *`<sup>1</sup>), so what you need to write is

```
n = get_int( prompt );
```

The expression `%n` is invalid in C, and that's what the compiler was choking on.

You can put this in a loop to repeat the operation while `n` is less than or equal to 0:

```
do {
  n = get_int( prompt );
} while ( n <= 0 );
```

---

1. And this is what I mean about CS50 being misleading.  A `char *` is not a *string*.  In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator.  For example, the string `"hello"` is represented as the sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`.  Strings are *stored* in arrays of character type.  *Under most circumstances*, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  So, when we're dealing with strings, we're *usually* dealing with expressions of type `char *`, but a `char *` isn't always a pointer to the first character in a string.